# Java 2d array and Bucket sort

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, bucket-sort

I am working on an assignment where we need to take a integer array and sort it using a Bucket Sort.

My issue comes when trying to increase to the next column, but only if there is an element already in the "bucket" already.

So, using my array below, 22 is the first element and will go in row 2 column 0, which is correct, but using i as the column is obviously not correct because it always increases the column and I eventually get an index out of bounds.

I can't wrap my head around how to correctly increase the index of the bucketArray column, only if there is an element in that position.  I've tried using an additional for loop that handled the column but that didn't work either.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!  I'm sure also there are other ways to create a bucket sort but the assignment said to use a 2d array for each bucket so I was trying to get it to work that way.

```
public class BucketSort {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       int intArray[] = {22, 45, 12, 8, 10, 6, 72, 81, 33, 18, 50, 14};
       int eachBucket[][] = new int[10][11];
       int j;
       double max = 81;
       int min = 6;
       int divider = (int)Math.ceil((max + 1) / 10);

       for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
           j = (int)Math.floor(intArray[i] / divider);
           eachBucket[j][i] = intArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 11th element to track how many elements in the current bucket have been used, something like this

```
   for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
       j = (int)Math.floor(intArray[i] / divider);
       eachBucket[j][eachBucket[j][10]] = intArray[i];
       eachBucket[j][10]++;
    }
```

The problem with a fixed-sized second dimension is if you have more that n elements to put into any one bucket.  Probably not a problem here.

Comment: No that's not a problem in this case.  I got to say, I feel a little stupid but I'm not really understanding how this is actually working.  Lets take the very first number (22), it's going to go into row 2 (j), but what exactly is column eachBucket[j][10]?  Please keep in mind I'm new to programming haha.

Comment: Oh I see!  eachBucket[j][10]  = 0, then you're adding 1 each time to that!  Brilliant

Comment: Is this a good way of doing something like this?  For this particular situation.  Also, if I know that the max elements per row can be 11, should I create an additional column just to keep track of the count?  Have you dealt with a situation like this before or did you come up with that off the top of your head?  Meaning, should I be kicking myself for not thinking that way or as you program and get experience do you get better at solving problems like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd do this real world, but I understand it as a programming assignment, and it did come from the top of my head....but take it with a grain of salt, I've been programming for a while...